# ReactJS Router - .push() , how to stop execution after one?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

RectJS Router here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Utilizing the 'push(pathOrLoc)' method from this page: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md

In iOS, if I have the following:

```
hashHistory.push({pathname:'/path1'});
hashHistory.push({pathname:'/path2'});
```

I will be navigated to '/path1' for a split second and then land on '/path2'.

What I'd expect to happen is that I get pushed to '/path1' and the code doesn't ever execute the second path.  How come both get executed?  Is there any way to stop the second from happening?

An example is that I have callbacks from a web url.. which opens the mobile app and pushes the user to the respective page ('/path1') and below that callback in my code I have the normal push which is if the user opens the app normally ('/path2').. but the callback /path1 is getting overwritten by /path2.

There are more than 2 path possibilities via various callbacks in my app, but the user always ends up on the last-most called even though I would expect that code to never be executed.  I'm not really wanting to throw in a bunch of new functions/variables/if statements to avoiding calling these pushes.

Is there anyway to disable this behavior?  I'm hoping for something like:

```
hashHistory.push({pathname:'/path1'}, {dontGoAnyhereElsePlzStop});
hashHistory.push({pathname:'/path2'});
```

And land on /path1 without ever touching /path2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push call doesn't do an immediate redirect, it behaves more like a state update, so code after it will continue to execute.

if you want to do one or the other try something like:

```
if (some_condition) {
    hashHistory.push({pathname:'/path1'});
} else {
    hashHistory.push({pathname:'/path2'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks; was afraid of this and wanted to confirm!